# How to get wireshark executables when building on linux

Tags: linux, wireshark

I'm trying to build wireshark on ubuntu 16.04 as described here: https://gist.github.com/syneart/2d30c075c140624b1e150c8ea318a978

But I'm getting only shared object without the executable.
Is there any way to get the executables as well?
This is the output:

```
[100%] Building C object plugins/epan/wimax/CMakeFiles/wimax.dir/wimax_harq_map_decoder.c.o
[100%] Building C object plugins/epan/wimax/CMakeFiles/wimax.dir/wimax_compact_dlmap_ie_decoder.c.o
[100%] Building C object plugins/epan/wimax/CMakeFiles/wimax.dir/wimax_compact_ulmap_ie_decoder.c.o
[100%] Building C object plugins/epan/wimax/CMakeFiles/wimax.dir/wimax_utils.c.o
[100%] Building C object plugins/epan/wimax/CMakeFiles/wimax.dir/crc.c.o
[100%] Building C object plugins/epan/wimax/CMakeFiles/wimax.dir/crc_data.c.o
[100%] Building C object plugins/epan/wimax/CMakeFiles/wimax.dir/wimax_tlv.c.o
[100%] Linking C shared module ../../../run/plugins/3.5/epan/wimax.so
[100%] Built target wimax

 

Build Success!
You can execute the Wireshark by command "sudo ./wireshark"
at "/home/devbox/wireshark/build/run"

dev@pc:~/wireshark/build/run (master=) % file wireshark
wireshark: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, 
interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32,
BuildID[sha1]=f71d989ae7cc28f81ca3077ae99fe46927d5fe24, not stripped
```

Comment: That *is* the executable. It's just a quirk of `file` which identifies some  types of executables as shared objects. Just run it and see.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum it's working properly.